# Import data between two strings in text file and delete imported data from file

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I need is to retrieve the data contained in a text file and delete the imported data. In fact, the short name for it is usually "cut".

First, look at the contents of the file.txt to fully understand the problem and to guide me:

```
Start

General           : Video
Format            : Matroska at 3 961 kb/s
Length            : 2.50 GiB for 1 h 30 min 12 s 928 ms

Video #1          : AVC at 3 320 kb/s
Aspect            : 1920 x 1080 (1.778) at 24.000 fps

Audio #2          : AC-3 at 640 kb/s
Infos             : 6 channel(s), 48.0 kHz
Language          : tr

Text #3           : UTF-8
Language          : tr

End
--- Passing Data ---
Start

General           : Second Video
Format            : AVI at 1 113 kb/s
Length            : 718 MiB for 1 h 30 min 12 s 552 ms

Video #0          : MPEG-4 Visual at 976 kb/s
Aspect            : 720 x 404 (1.782) at 24.000 fps

Audio #1          : MPEG Audio at 128 kb/s
Infos             : 2 channel(s), 48.0 kHz

End
```

As you can see in the file, Start and End specifiers come at certain intervals. I use these specifiers to get the data between them. My code is like this:

```
f = open('file.txt','r+' , encoding='utf-8')
s = f.read()
start = s.find("Start") + len("Start")
end = s.find("End")
substring = s[start:end]
f.close()
print(substring)
```

But this code just retrieves the data instead of truncating it. Therefore, it prevents me from passing to a data. Because `s.find("Start")` and `s.find("End")` fetches only the first data.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: open file again for writing and write `s[end:]`. You work with string in memory - it will not crop text in file. And to crop from beginning you have to write again all data which you want to keep in file. Files can't crop data like you can crop strings. BTW: if you have something before `start` then you may need to write `s[:start]` and `s[end:]`

Comment: if you want to get next element then use `s.find("Start", end)` and it will start searching at position `end`. So you can run it in loop and get all elements without cutting.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I'm not sure if it's going to be exactly what I want. I did this:
`end_after_end = s[end:]
print(end_after_end)`
and I got this result:
`End

Start

General           : Second Video
Format            : AVI at 1 113 kb/s
Length            : 718 MiB for 1 h 30 min 12 s 552 ms
....

End`

all good so far. But how do I complete the continuation of the loop in the file?

So I got the second file. So how would I get it if it was the third file?

Comment: you get result on screen - but this can't save it in file. You have to open file for writing and `write(s[end:])`. But better remove `End` at the beginning `write(s[end+len("End"):])`

Comment: With the `s[end:]` command, did we go to the **end text** at the end of the file or to the next **end text**?

Comment: we get text from word `"End"` to the end of file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File can't work like strings. If you want to remove some part from beginning or middle of file then you have to read all text to memory, edit it in memory, and write all back to file. So you have to open file for writing and write `s[:start]` and `s[end:]`

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r' , encoding='utf-8')
s = f.read()
start = s.find("Start") + len("Start")
end = s.find("End")
substring = s[start:end]
f.close()
print(substring)

f = open('file.txt', 'w' , encoding='utf-8')
f.write(s[:start])
f.write(s[end+len("End"):])
f.close()
```

But if you want to work with all blocks `Start...End` then you don't have to crop it but you can use option `start_position` in `find()` to get next elements.

```
start = s.find("Start", end) + len("Start")
end = s.find("End", start)
```

like

```
end = 0

while True:
    start = s.find("Start", end)
    if start == -1:
        break
    start += len("Start")
    end = s.find("End", start)
    substring = s[start:end]
    print(substring)
    end += len("End")
```

OR you can repeate code for with substring `s[end:]`

```
s = s[end:]
```

like

```
while True:
    start = s.find("Start")
    if start == -1:
        break
    start += len("Start")
    end = s.find("End", start)
    substring = s[start:end]
    print(substring)
    s = s[end:]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Therefore, it prevents me from passing to a data." but I would use [s.split("end")](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to separate and make othe string operations from there because you would have everything to "end" separated in each index of the array. Maybe using [splitlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) after for an array of the lines of each block of "start/end".

```py
f = open('file.txt','r+' , encoding='utf-8')
   s = f.read()
   blocksOfData = s.split("end")
   f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding f.truncate(0) before you close the file will erase all of the contents of file.txt.

```
f = open('file.txt','r+' , encoding='utf-8')
s = f.read()
start = s.find("Start") + len("Start")
end = s.find("End")
substring = s[start:end]
f.truncate(0)
f.close()
print(substring)
```

Comment: This deletes all content. I don't want to delete all content. I need to delete the data received with `substring`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like:

```
import re

re_blocks = re.compile(r"Start\s*(.+?)\s*End", re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    file_string = file.read()

for match in re_blocks.finditer(file_string):
    sub_string = match[1]
    print(sub_string)
```

Comment: No, this actually returns all the contents of the file. I want to bring everything starting with Start and ending with End in the file separately.